# JspWriter write versus print

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm developing some custom JSP tags. In my `SimpleTag.doTag()` I grab the `JspContext` and call `getOut()` to get the `JspWriter`. When writing to `JspWriter`, what's the different between `write(String)` and `print(String)`? Should I be calling one instead of the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The print() method can buffer, the write() method is inherited from the Writer class and cannot - so you may get better performance from the JspWriter's print() method.

In addition, the print() method is overloaded to take many different types of objects as an argument, whereas the write method deals in Strings and chars only.

See the [JspWriter javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html) for more details.

Comment: So it sounds like print is the preferred method.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, but I'd say yes in most cases - it's specifically  purposed to be used with JSP, as opposed to the generic Writer abstract class which you'd need to use to leverage polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

from the javadoc:

The '**write**' function was inherited from java.io.writer .

The '**print**' function: prints "null" if the argument was null. Otherwise, the string's characters are written to the JspWriter's buffer or, if no buffer is used, directly to the underlying writer.